# Does potential difference depend on the size of an object

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

Let's say object A has received a number x of electrons and is now at a 1v higher potential relative to a neutral ground.

Now if object B which is 2 times bigger than object A receives the same number x of electrons, will it reach the same potential difference relative to the ground or no, (In my opinion yes because batteries can be in different sizes and deliver the same voltage)

Also does it change depending on the shape of the object. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The number of electrons on an object really doesn't have much to do with its potential. What matters is **how those electrons are arranged** on the object, and, in particular, **how much energy it takes to push electrons into that arrangement**.

We already have a term for this concept - the *capacitance*. An object with high capacitance stores charge in an arrangement that makes it relatively easy to add more; in contrast, it takes much more work to add charge to an object with low capacitance. The work you do to put charge on an object is equal to the amount of potential energy the object has, just as the amount of work you do pushing a (frictionless) object up a hill is equal to the gravitational potential energy it has at the top of the hill. So, for the same amount of charge, an object with *lower* capacitance will be at a *higher* potential.

Capacitance in general depends on the shape and size of an object, and the rule of thumb is that bigger objects generally have higher capacitance (there are lots and lots of exceptions to this, so refrain from actually using this unless you're comparing objects that are the same shape and composition). This makes sense, because a bigger object will have a lower charge density for the same charge; this means that the electric field is generally lower, and consequently the electrostatic force on incoming charges is lower. Taken to the extreme, a gargantuan object like the Earth has ridiculously high capacitance, so you can add as much charge to it as you want (on any reasonable human scale) without changing the potential. This is why we always use "ground" (the potential of the Earth) as a reference and charge sink.

As an aside, batteries don't really store charge. They store chemical energy, and use that chemical energy to separate electrons and ions.

Comment: Wait isn't potential = a difference in the number of charges an object has in comparison to an other , Like all the electric fields calculations relay on a difference of charges , so how isn't it related to the number of electrons ? . Thanks